# Android Capture current screen. not Activity

Tags: java, android, native

about android capture.
The function of the application is that when you press a specific button,
One overlay button located at the top of the home screen of the device is generated.
When I press the overlay button, I want to capture the screen of the device I'm currently viewing, not the application screen.
I want to capture the top screen, but only the activity done by the application is captured.
How should I capture the screen I'm currently viewing?

Comment: You don't.  Its a security issue-  if you could capture the screen, you could capture private info in other apps.  Imagine launching their banking app then taking a screenshot to get their account into.  As such, this functionality was removed a LONG time ago.

Comment: Gabe Sechan 

However, among the apps in the store, there are apps that do this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried researching this problem *for days* before but I do not think that it is *possible*. Then I have an idea that instead of try to screen shot "outside" of app, we can use Service to keep our app alive, make back ground transparent and **detect screenshot action of device**. You may want to try [com.abangfadli.shotwatch](https://github.com/abangfadli/shotwatch)